# How to make a sprite jump up and return to original position?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am just trying to make my game character, which is a texture (ball), to jump up in the air and then return back down to the position that it started at when the screen is pressed. I was just wondering if someone could give me a code example or help me to do this with my current code which is below. I have basically just drawn the background and the ball texture and positioned the ball where I want it to start the jump. The ball texture is what I want to make jump straight up.

```
    public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture background;
    Texture ball;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        background = new Texture("gamebackground.png");

        ball = new Texture("ball2.png");
        ball.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
    }

    @Override   
    public void render   () { 
        batch.begin();  
        float scaleFactor = 2.0f;   
        batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight    ());
        batch.draw(ball, 80, 145, ball.getWidth() * scaleFactor, ball.getHeight() *     scaleFactor);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to get an answer that works

Comment: Wtf then why you accepted the answer in the other question?

Comment: Because I did what he proposed but it still wasn't working after I accepted it. My bad

Comment: Your approach to this problem is pretty misguided. If your end goal is really just a ball that moves up and down, you should look into using an Actor for the ball and apply Actions to it. If you are trying to turn this into a more complete game, you should start with a World and Ball object and code some simple physics for the world. On button press apply a positive Y speed to the ball, and have the world continuously apply a negative Y speed to all movable objects in the world. Here's a tutorial: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-2-Actions.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping a `y` coordinate for your ball, and then manipulate this in the `render` method by adding a velocity to it.

Also, apply a gravity to the velocity to make the ball change direction at the 'top'.

There are many ways of achieving the above including (but not limited to using animated **libGDX** `Actor`s or by relying on a physics library (like **Box2D**, for example). Each different way will have some aspects that work well or not so well for your particular game.

A bare bones implementation could look something like this;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture ball;
    float x;
    float y;
    float vy = 0;
    float g = -64;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        ball = new Texture("ball2.png");

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) { return false; }
            public boolean keyUp(int keycode) { return false; }
            public boolean keyTyped(char character) { return false; }

            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                // Only allow new jump if already at ground level;
                if (y == 0.0f) {
                    vy = 128; // Set an upwards velocity for the y position
                }
                return false;
            }

            public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) { return false; }
            public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) { return false; }
            public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) { return false; }
            public boolean scrolled(int amount) { return false; }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Add the 'vy' velocity to the y position, scaled by how much time has elapsed
        // also make sure y is never smaller than 0, 0 representing the 'ground' in this example.
        y = Math.max(0, y + vy * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        // Apply gravity, 'g', to the velocity so that it slows down and then turns around
        vy += g * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(ball, x, y);
        batch.end();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ground as an initial position, i strongly suggest you to learn and use Box2D for LibGdx. It handles all physical interactions. Give an initial speed or apply force to your object and let Box2D handle the rest.